# Thunderbird does not open when using the indicator menu

Tags: unity, thunderbird

Running Ubuntu 11.10.

The mail application we are using is Thunderbird using a POP3 protocol with a couple of email accounts.

When an email arrives we get the usual on-screen indication.

However, something has changed recently.  It used to be that if we went to the messaging indicator menu (the mail envelope) we could click the inbox menu item and Thunderbird would open (i.e. become the active application).  This was completely consistent whether Thunderbird had already been opened and was sitting in the background or whether it was unopened.

Now, if Thunderbird is already open but with another application active, then all that happens is the Thunderbird icon in the sidebar wiggles.  It works perfectly fine if Thunderird is closed, as it will open Thunderbird and make it the active application.  This is really irritating as it would be nice to go back to the old behaviour.

We have made no configuration changes and so the only thing I can think of is that a recent patch has altered the setting/behaviour in some way.  Is there a way of changing the behaviour so that clicking on the indicator menu always opens up Thunderbird and makes it the active application?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).